# Website Search Query to list out all your products

Tags: search

What search query to enter into the search bar present in an **E-Commerce website** developed by Magento which will list out all the products present on that E-Commerce Website? 
For Example, for websites developed using `Presta Shop` if you enter a single space and hit search it will list out all the products present on the website. This is true for any website developed using the Presta Shop Platform. I was wondering if there exists any `similar hack for Magento` Websites?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rest api, specifically [catalogProductRepositoryV1](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogProductRepositoryV1). 
There is no such search "hack" otherwise.

Else you'd have to write your own module using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` or `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`.

As for your mentioned 'presta shop' hack ... . I would consider that a serious performance issue.